# Why does error occurs in Linux, not occuring in Visual Studio

Tags: c, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use Windows Subsystems for Linux(WSL), Ubuntu. I try compile simple code.

I get errors in WSL.

But, it works well in Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't use `gets` which is deprecated, and don't use `gets_s` which is non standard, but use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead: `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);`. Read the documentation of `fgets` carefully. And please for your next question: don't post pictures of text, but post text as text. Read the pages in the [help], and learn how to format a question properly, the investment in time for this is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gets_s()` is a "secure" alternative to `gets()` defined in the Microsoft C Runtime Library.  It is not included in the GNU C library used in Linux.

For portability use `fgets()` on the `stdin` input stream instead.